# willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation not called in root view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created the one rootviewcontroller , and then make that geosensitive by writing

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

In rootviewcontroller `willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation` method is called and images are resizing.

I also have some views on it, but when I rotate the screen the view will be rotate but the images are not resizing though I have used the same

```
-(void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
}
```

method but it cannot called.
So, what can I do? Please help me.

Comment: Your method is probably getting called, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Question could still need a more descriptive title.

Comment: Descriptive title and properly using markdown (surround inline code with `` and use the code format button for larger blocks of code) make your question easier for others to answer. I've fixed these for you.

Comment: no its not calling,I have checked it using break points

Comment: @jaynaiphone: that's what I said. it *is* getting called, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you pushing view controllers on to a stack, or do you just have subviews in your rootviewcontroller view?

Answer (score 5):

This got me too.  I think you'll find the answer if you look at that header file for UIViewController.  There are comments in there which state that you may override **EITHER**

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:

**OR** any of the following

- (void)willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- (void)didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
- (void)willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation: duration:

Apparently if you override the first one, that's the only one that will be called.  If you want feedback from each stage of the rotation, use any of the ones in the 2nd set, but LEAVE OUT the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider is that you have overridden shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method to allow rotations other then the default of portrait.

For example :

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

If you don't do this, your implementated methods won't be called.